# Using Python decorators to enforce standard method signature

Tags: python, decorator, python-decorators

I have a library with lots of functions. I want to be consistent with the basic method pattern. I want all to the methods to take a context as the first parameter and keyword arg that defaults to 0.

```
library_function(context, ..., default=0)
```

Is there a way I could use python decorators to turn

```
bobs_function(foo, bar=None)
```

into

```
bobs_library_function(context, foo, bar=None, default=0)
```

The goal of this is to provide a shorthand for declaring library functions. Instead of explicitly adding the context and the default every time.

Comment: Can you give some more clarification?  Are your examples of `bobs_function` and `bobs_library_function` meant to be examples of how the functions are *defined*, or how they're *called*?  If it's how they're called, where do you expect the `context` variable to come from?  That is, if you write `bobs_function(foo, bar=None)` as a function call, where is the "right" solution supposed to look to find the thing `context` that is inserted as the first argument?

Comment: The goal was to be able to create a shorthand for declaring that a test takes a context and a default. But you either have to explicitely declare that the function takes a context as input, or I have to user *args, **kwargs as the arguments, but having *args and **kwargs as input is more onerous than manually typing context, default=0

Answer (score 1):

You can make this work if you only allow passed keyword arguments in your wrapped functions:

```
import functools

def lib(fn):
    @functools.wraps(fn)
    def wrapped(context, default=0, **kwargs):
        print context, default
        return fn(**kwargs)
    return wrapped

@lib
def bobs_function(foo, bar=None):
    print foo
    print bar


bobs_function('context', foo='foo', bar='bar', default='default')
```

prints:

```
context default
foo
bar
```

Answer (score -2):

The more I look and think about this the more I am convinced the answer is no.

I want to be able to access the context and the default from inside bobs function. The hope was that I could come up with a handy shorthand that would ensure that I wrote method signatures that follow the convention.

The problem is that I have to ahead of time declare the arguments that `bob_function` takes. If it takes a positional argument then adding a new positional argument is going to mess everything up.

So my first thought of

```
@library_function
def bobs_function(foo, bar=None):
     ....
```

magically changing the method signature won't work.

My next thought is to reverse it

```
@library_function(foo, bar=None)
def bobs_function(*args, **kwargs):
    ...
```

but that is not even syntactically correct. And I am left with the unpleasant result of having to fish my variables out of the args and charges.

So to summarize my issue. If I want to use context I have to pass it in. I can't modify the actual declared parameters of `bobs_function` so the only way I could pass the context in is to use *args **kwargs, which is far more unpleasant than just typing

```
bobs_library_function(context, foo, bar=None, default=0)
```

to begin with.

Comment: Don't use answer to explain better your question. Comment and modify (or delete your question) and comment the other answers to tell what is the misunderstanding. As you have already understand by yourself what you need is wrong defined but you didn't mention it in your question: maybe in that case the question would be down voted and closed.

Comment: I am not trying to explain the question. I am trying to explain the answer. The answer is no. You can mutate the values passed into a function, you can wrap the function, you can replace a function entirely with a new function, but what you cannot do is mutate the declared parameters of a function. You can't use the context or default unless they are declared explicitly or in * / ** fashion and that puts more work on the function writer. The question was whether something was possible, and the answer is no.

Comment: Where is in the question the mentions of use context and default in the original function and not in the wrapped one?